# Getting error /usr/lib/../lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0' when trying to complie newest version of vim

Tags: vim

I try to install the newest version of vim on Red Hat 6.6.
I use the script below to run configure:

```
# change to folder where vim sources are
cd ~/vim

# here I compiled newest version of libuuid.
LIBDIR="/home/muellc1b/uuid/lib"


export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBDIR:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH # prepend to path
export LDFLAGS="-L$LIBDIR"
#export LIBS="-llibuuid.so"

./configure \
    --prefix=/home/muellc1b/vim_installation
     #LIBS="-l$LIBDIR" \
     #LDFLAGS="-L$LIBDIR"
```

When trying to run the makefile, I get the following errors:

```
  gcc   -L/home/muellc1b/uuid/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed [...]   -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lelf -lnsl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm
/usr/lib/../lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone point me to a solution on how to correctly link my custom library?

Answer (score 10):

As I saw, you got a satisfactory [answer here](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1961) where the solution was to  run the configure script normally, open `src/auto/config.mk`, and change the line `X_PRE_LIBS = -lSM -lICE -lXpm` to `X_PRE_LIBS = -luuid -lSM -lICE -lXpm`. Then do `make`.

I had exactly the same error message, but when compiling PCL (point cloud library). The error had a different cause and different solution. I'll add it here, as this page came up when looking for solution - perhaps it will help someone.

My problem was that when doing `cmake ..` before `make` it gave warnings like this:

```
CMake Warning at cmake/pcl_targets.cmake:194 (add_library):
Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target pcl_io because
files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:
```

All the directories that were referenced were under `anaconda3/lib`. I ignored it and `make` gave me the same error `` libSM.so: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0' `` and some more :). The solution was to remove anaconda lib folder from the path, and build again. In detail:

1. delete build directory and create it again
2. `echo $PATH` and look for anaconda lib directory
3. Copy the PATH output from previous step and remove reference to anaconda folder
4. execute `PATH=[MODIFIED_PATH]` where `[MODIFIED_PATH]` is the result from previous step
5. Execute `echo $PATH` again to see that anaconda directory has been removed
6. build the project again in the same terminal window

Now the process uses system libraries, not the anaconda ones and compilation succeeds.

An example of modified PATH: if the original was `/home/you/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` then the modified one is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

NB! You probably do not want to change the PATH permanently (your anaconda installation might stop working) that is why it is done from the terminal not from .bashrc file.

Comment: In my case, I found that it was picking `libsm` from a different source. The final cure was `conda install -c conda-forge xorg-libsm` and rebuild

Comment: @wander95, thank you very much. You solved my problem!

Comment: @wander95 Thank you, it solved my problem too, by `conda install -c conda-forge xorg-libsm`